# Como eliminar o espaço no topo que minha DIV deixa?

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma DIV de deixa um espaço entre ela e a parte superior do navegador, veja: http://www.roteirodoimovel.com.br/modelos/3/teste.php

CSS:

```
    .element {
position:relative;
display: table;
width:960px;
height:120px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0px;
background-color:#000000;
border:0px;
    }
```

Tentei várias coisas mas sem sucesso. Preciso que minha **DIV** fique colada na parte superior do navegador.

Comment: Verifique se tem margem ou padding no elemento que contém essa div. Se não tiver, vá subindo na hierarquia até achar o culpado. É bem possível que as margens estejam "colapsando".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte css:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}
```

Comment: margin: 0 auto; é para deixar minha div centralizada

Comment: Mude o seletor de * para body entao, e tente novamente. O seletor '*' significa que irá atribuir a todos elementos.

Comment: Beleza rapaz, funcionou certinho. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz em saber!

Answer (score 0):

Tente editar para:

```
.element{
  position:fixed;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou..

Comment: @Gladion Neuza Perosini Tente agora editei minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
.element {
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  width: 960px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 0px;
}
```

Explicação:

Isso acontece porque o todo o elemento tem um espaço de **20px** com a parte superior do navegador, e não adianta você colocar **0px**, porque há um espaço de **20px** entre a div e a parte superior do navegador.

Espero ter ajudado **:)**